# What we can use for mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta in Android?

Tags: android

What we can use for mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta in Android? It is use in ios, I have to use its equivalent in Android.

Answer (score 1):

mapView.getLatitudeSpan() returns the current latitude span (from the top edge to the bottom edge of the map) in decimal degrees multiplied by one million.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/

Comment: I have a arraylist of lattitudes and longitudes which I have to show on map. But I want to display a fixed number of pins when user zooms out or zooms in.How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed member"? What if they zoom into a location in the middle of the ocean? Is there always the same fixed number wherever the zoom in/out?